# Proof of divisibility by 2 and 3 if and only if divisible by 6

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I can't find a way of proving that:

> For integer a, a is divisible by 2 and divisible by 3 if and only if a is divisible by 6.

I’m not sure where to go from here. Any help would be great!

Comment: "not sure where to go from here", you make it sound like you've tried something.

Comment: Let $a\in \Bbb Z$.

$\implies:$ Suppose $a$ is divisible by both $2$ and $3$.

Then, by definition of divisibility, there exist $m,n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $2m=a=3n$.

Therefore $3|2m$. Since $\gcd (2,3)=1$ it follows that $3|m$. This means that there exists $k\in \Bbb Z$ such that $3k=m$.

Substitute $m$ by $3k$ back on $2m\color{grey}{(=a)}$ to conclude.

$\Longleftarrow :$ Suppose $a$ is divisible by $6$, then there exists $x\in \Bbb Z$ such that $6x=a$. From here follows $2\cdot 3\cdot x=a$. Now use associativity and commutativy of $\cdot$ to conclude.

Comment: Let $x$ is divisible by $a$ and by $b$ 

Let the highest powers of a prime $p$ in $a,b$ are $p_a,p_b$ respectively, so $x$ must be divisible by max$(p_a,p_b)\implies x$ is divisible by lcm $(a,b)$

Conversely, if $x$ is divisible by lcm $(a,b),$  it will be divisible by by both

Comment: @GitGud I tried messing around with least common multiples like what lab-bhattacharjee suggested (I guess I should've mentioned that), but I thought the reasoning was too simple. Thanks for your idea; I think that will work.

Answer (score 3):

If $6\mid n$ then $2\mid 6\mid n$ and $3\mid 6\mid n$ so that $2\mid n$ and $3\mid n$. Conversely, if $2\mid n$ and $3\mid n$ then $6\mid n$ because $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime: more explicity, we have $3\mid n=2b$ so that $3\mid (2b)$ which implies $3\mid b$ (by [Euclide's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)).